# What's the difference between a $2$-sided and $2$-sided strip polytan

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

There are $14$ $2$-sided tetratans and $13$ $2$-sided strip tetratans.  The sets are identical, except the square is missing in the strip version.  My best guess is that for strips, no vertex can have an edge count of $n$.  Does anyone know the exact definitions?

Comment: I's *guess* that in a strip tetratan, all elementary triangles have exactly two edge-connected neighbours, except for two endpoints which only have a single neighbour. But I have no reference to support this guess.

Comment: My guess was poorly thought out and flat wrong.  Perhaps this is restating your guess, but it appears that for strips the free edge count must equal n + 2.  Since the non-strip square composed of four triangles has a free edge count of four it's excluded from the strip version.  Search for "tetraboloes" in google books and see the 18 Jan 1962 copy of New Scientist.

Comment: If you look [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolyformExplorer/), you will find fourth order strip shapes that have three edge-connected neighbors.  After much puzzling, I think these two rules account for the differences:  (1) No square formed from two triangles can have more than two edge-connected neighbors.  (2) No vertex can be internally isolated.  If someone sees this and can confirm this, it would be appreciated.